# Cannot use SQL Server CE 4.0 in Visual Studio editor

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I can't use SQL Server CE 4.0 as a data provider in Visual Studio, only 3.5, but it was installed, in `machine.config` I see SQL Server CE 4.0, but tokens of versions was equals. Help what need to do that i was able to use it in VS?

screen1:

[image]

screen2:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if installing [SQL CE Tools for Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212219)  (direct download link) fixes that. The link was provided from [this blog post by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx):

> Once SP1 is installed, you’ll also then need to install the SQL CE
>   Tools for Visual Studio download.  This is a separate download that
>   enables the SQL CE tooling support for VS 2010 SP1.